# How do you convert a Map<Key, Value> into an array of {"keyprop" : key, "valueprop" : value} with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, serialization, jackson

I am trying to do the following

Given

```
Map<String, String> labels = {"en_GB" : "English", "de" : "German", "it" : "Italian"}....
```

I would like to use Jackson to serialize it to

```
[{"language" : "en_GB", "label" : "English"}, {"language" : "de", "label" : "German"}, {"language" : "it", "label" : "Italian"}]
```

Essentially splitting the map into arrays of objects, with the key and value as separate properties

Instead of

```
 {"en_GB" : "English", "de" : "German", "it" : "Italian"}
```

I have searched the entirety of Jackson docs and i cannot find an answer to this. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: define a middle POJO and convert map<String,String> to list of middle object**

- first to define a middle POJO:

  ```java
  public class LanguageInfo {
      private String language;
      private String label;
  }
  ```
- convert map to list of middle POJO and serialize list to string:

  ```java
  Map<String, String> labels = new HashMap<>();
  labels.put("en_GB", "English");
  labels.put("de", "German");
  labels.put("it", "Italian");

  List<LanguageInfo> languageInfoList = labels.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> {
        LanguageInfo info = new LanguageInfo();
        info.setLabel(entry.getValue());
        info.setLanguage(entry.getKey());
        return info;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(languageInfoList));
  ```

*output is:*

```json
[
    {
        "language":"de",
        "label":"German"
    },
    {
        "language":"en_GB",
        "label":"English"
    },
    {
        "language":"it",
        "label":"Italian"
    }
]
```

**Method 2: define a `JsonSerializer` and use this to do serialize work**

Assume you want to directly serialize the below class：

```java
@Data
public class LanguageInfos {
    private Map<String, String> labels;
}
```

- First，define a `JsonSerializer` to serialize `LanguageInfos`:

  need middle POJO `LanguageInfo` defined above：

  ```java
  public class LanguageInfosJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LanguageInfos> {

      @Override
      public void serialize(LanguageInfos languageInfos, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
          // LanguageInfo defined in below code
          List<LanguageInfo> languageInfoList = languageInfos.getLabels().entrySet().stream()
              .map(entry -> {
                  LanguageInfo info = new LanguageInfo();
                  info.setLabel(entry.getValue());
                  info.setLanguage(entry.getKey());
                  return info;
              }).collect(Collectors.toList());
          jsonGenerator.writeObject(languageInfoList);
      }
  }
  ```

  no need middle POJO：

  ```java
  public class LanguageInfosJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LanguageInfos> {

      @Override
      public void serialize(LanguageInfos languageInfos, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
          jsonGenerator.writeStartArray(languageInfos.getLabels().size());
          languageInfos.getLabels().entrySet().forEach(new Consumer<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
              @SneakyThrows
              @Override
              public void accept(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
                      ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
                      node.put("language",entry.getKey());
                      node.put("label",entry.getValue());
                      jsonGenerator.writeObject(node);
              }
          });
          jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
      }
  }
  ```
- Second，register this Serializer to a ObjectMapper object:

  ```java
  SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
  simpleModule.addSerializer(LanguageInfos.class, new LanguageInfosJsonSerializer());
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
  ```
- Third,use the ObjectMapper serialize directly：

  ```java
  Map<String, String> labels = new HashMap<>();
  labels.put("en_GB", "English");
  labels.put("de", "German");
  labels.put("it", "Italian");

  LanguageInfos languageInfos = new LanguageInfos();
  languageInfos.setLabels(labels);

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
  simpleModule.addSerializer(LanguageInfos.class, new LanguageInfosJsonSerializer());
  mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
  System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(languageInfos));
  ```

*output is:*

```json
[
    {
        "language":"de",
        "label":"German"
    },
    {
        "language":"en_GB",
        "label":"English"
    },
    {
        "language":"it",
        "label":"Italian"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Are you perhaps aware of an annotation-only/declarative way to do this instead of creating a wrapper class? The existing code base has a class like LanguageInfos that contains the map as the only property, and i would like to serialize this class with the format i mentioned

Comment: @dac1n  you can define yourself `JsonSerializer` to do what your want.I have post simple code about that.